# USB Drive cannot detect in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, hardware-failure, disk-utility, removable

Have you ever plugged in a USB drive or any external device with a hard drive and wondered why you cannot see it in My Computer?

I often have, **I believe my USB is not broke** .. because if I plugin the USB to another computer could be seen / detected.
I tried following this tutorial
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22251/find-your-missing-usb-drive-in-windows-7-vista/

but I am afraid of going wrong, and caused my data is lost.
is there any easy way around this problem?

many thank's for your attentions Guys ..

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial?  Did it work?  Have you tried plugging the USB into another computer?

Comment: yes, but not until the end because there are steps which should move the drive name (Manage disk), I am confused.
yes, no problem when I plug the USB in another computer.